# Get arrays in all directions from a single point in a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

What's a pythonic way of getting a list representing the line of values out from a point in a 2-dimensional matrix in each of the 8 directions? For example, if I have:

```
array([[0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]], dtype=object)
```

and I choose the point (1,2) (value 11), I would get the list of points above (1,2) until the top, which is [6,1]. I also get the list going to the top right until hitting an edge which is [7,3]. Etc. for each of the 8 directions. I don't want to use separate for loops for each direction, that seems pretty unpythonic not to mention a lot of code for a simple-ish task. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems tricky. I can think of defining 4 lists of tuples of coordinates, contemplating the 4 directions (each containing both sides), and then just looping over the indexing arrays and indexing the array with them

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, could you clarify? Sorry :P

Comment: The point at [1, 2] is 7.  Do you mean [2, 1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to slice, dice, twist and mangle the array.  Here is a function which does just that ... whatever 'that' is.

The array:

```
>>> a = np.arange(25, dtype=int).reshape([5, 5])

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

Sample Code:

```
def directions(a, r, c) -> dict:
    """Return all vectors from an ndarray.
    
    Args:
        a (np.ndarray): Array.
        r (int): Starting row.
        c (int): Starting column.
    
    :Directions:
        1: up
        2: up/right
        3: right
        4: down/right
        5: down
        6: down/left
        7: left
        8: up/left

    Returns:
        A dict containing all eight directions of rotation,
        starting with the top, moving clockwise.
    
    """
    v = {}
    v['1'] = a[r-1::-1, c]
    v['2'] = np.diagonal(a[r::-1, c:])[1:]
    v['3'] = a[r, c+1:]
    v['4'] = np.diagonal(a[r:, c:])[1:]
    v['5'] = a[r+1:, c]
    v['6'] = np.diagonal(a[r:, c::-1])[1:]
    v['7'] = a[r, c-1::-1]
    v['8'] = np.diagonal(a[r::-1, c::-1])[1:]
    return v
```

Output:

```
>>> directions(a, 2, 1)

{'1': array([6, 1]),
 '2': array([7, 3]),
 '3': array([12, 13, 14]),
 '4': array([17, 23]),
 '5': array([16, 21]),
 '6': array([15]),
 '7': array([10]),
 '8': array([5])}
```

Comment: I know this is kinda a more complex question, and I should have put it in the original, but is there a not-too-hard way to somehow associate a point with each value? That is, in your example, instead of just the list [6,1] there would be the list [((1, 1), 6), ((0, 0), 1)]? Or something like that?